# Properly forward return value in Perl

Tags: perl, return-type

I'm pretty new to Perl and have a hard time wrapping my head around its very implicit type-system. What I like to achieve is a simple wrapper function that has the same signature as the function it wraps so it can be used in its place.

So let's say I have an existing function `orig` that I want to wrap. I takes a number of input arguments and has different return types based on those arguments. As long as I write the wrapper in the following way the return types are the same as the original function and it all works nicely:

```
sub wrapper {
    my ($first) = @_;
    print "before. first argument: $first\n";
    return orig(@_);
}
```

However, if I want to execute some code in the wrapper after the execution of `orig` I don't know how I preserve the types. From my understanding, the same way the input to a perl function is always an array of scalars so is the output. So the solution then should be this:

```
sub wrapper {
    my ($first) = @_;
    print "before. first argument: $first\n";
    my @result = orig(@_);
    print "after";
    return @result;
}
```

But that does not seem to work as expected. What am I missing? How to write such wrapper function that it works properly for arbitrary return types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> From my understanding, the same way the input to a perl function is
>   always an array of scalars so is the output.

No, not quite.

Perl functions can be called in list context, scalar context, or void context.

```
some_function(@args);                  # void
my $result  = some_function(@args);    # scalar
my @results = some_function(@args);    # list
```

Many of Perl's built-in functions act differently according to which context they are called. For example `grep` returns a list of results in list context, and a count of results in scalar context.

If you are writing your own function and wish to behave differently in different contexts, the function can use the `wantarray` keyword to detect what context it's been called in. `wantarray` returns true for list context, false for scalar context, and undef for void context.

Even if you are not consciously wanting to write a function which behaves differently according to context, you may end up doing so accidentally by returning a context-sensitive expression such as `grep`, or `map`, or an array (arrays in scalar context return their length).

The correct way to wrap a function without breaking context is this. And yes, I realise it ain't pretty.

```
sub wrapper {
   my ($first) = @_;
   print "before. first argument: $first\n";
   my @result = 
      wantarray         ? orig(@_) :
      defined wantarray ? scalar orig(@_) :
      do { orig(@_); () };
   print "after";
   wantarray ? @result : $result[0];
}
```

Now, if your wrapper doesn't need to alter `@_`, and doesn't need to alter the return values, then [Class::Method::Modifiers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers) can make this a bit easier:

```
use Class::Method::Modifiers;

sub wrapper { orig(@_) }  # do nothing in the wrapper itself

before wrapper => sub {
   my ($first) = @_;
   print "before. first argument: $first\n";
};

after wrapper => sub {
   print "after";
};
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Doing the wantarray dispatching makes it work. However, I'll try the approach with Class::Method::Modifiers, since that would be the most elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's a better way to do what you want in Perl, but since you specify only the *mechanism* I can tell you only how to make it work.

The return value of a Perl subroutine depends on the *context* of the call. Within the subroutine you can use the built-in operator `wantarray` to detect the context -- it will return a *true* value if the call was in list context, and *false* otherwise.

So to pass on the value that another subroutine would return in the same context, you would have to write `wrapper` like this

```
sub wrapper {
    my ($first) = @_;

    print "before. first argument: $first\n";

    if (wantarray) {
      my @result = orig(@_);
      print "after";
      return @result;
    }
    else {
      my $result = orig(@_);
      print "after";
      return $result;
    }
}
```

But bear in mind that a given subroutine is probably meant to be called in *either* scalar *or* list context. Writing something that behaves differently according to context is rare, so you would normally want only one of these two conditional branches depending on the behaviour of `orig`.

Comment: This solution does not distinguish between `! wantarray` and `! defined wantarray`. Some subs do in fact return different values depending on those, so this wrapper is not completely transparent.